# How to read a file in PureScript (readFile)

Tags: purescript

While testing, I’d like to read and write a file from and to disk (JSON in, JSON out). How do I do this in PureScript? In Haskell I have something like

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  input <- readFile "input.json"
  writeFile "output.json" $ process input
```

All my attempts so far have failed, including trying to use `readFile` from `import Node.FS.Sync`.

BTW, if there is any other (better) way of reading in my JSON file, let me know. (I am not a JavaScript expert but I would like to port some — strict — Haskell code to JS so that it can be used elsewhere.)

Comment: What error did you get from `readFile`?

Comment: Another way to read JSON files on Node is to use `require`.

Comment: I get `Unknown value bind`. Maybe I forgot `import Prelude`, hang on…

Comment: No `import Prelude` is definitely the issue then.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working. I also had to switch to `readTextFile` and `writeTextFile` to get away from type `Buffer` so as to be able to process the file, and had to find out how to specify the encoding: `Node.Encoding.UTF8`.

Answer (score 11):

Or with purescript 0.12

```
module Main where

import Prelude
import Effect (Effect)
import Effect.Console (log)

import Node.Encoding (Encoding(..))
import Node.FS.Sync (readTextFile)

main :: Effect Unit
main = do
  log =<< readTextFile UTF8 "input.json"
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a full working example that reads and prints a file.

```
module Main where

import Prelude (Unit)

import Control.Bind ((=<<))
import Control.Monad.Eff (Eff)
import Control.Monad.Eff.Console (CONSOLE, log)
import Control.Monad.Eff.Exception (EXCEPTION)

import Node.Encoding (Encoding(..))
import Node.FS (FS)
import Node.FS.Sync (readTextFile)

main :: forall e. Eff (console :: CONSOLE, exception :: EXCEPTION, fs :: FS | e) Unit
main = do
  log =<< readTextFile UTF8 "input.json"
```

Dependencies:

- purescript-console
- purescript-eff
- purescript-math
- purescript-node-fs-aff
- purescript-control

Comment: I think err :: EXCEPTION has been renamed to exception :: EXCEPTION.